# React native file system to read directory recursively to get sub folder and items in it

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I can able to read the files in a directory using following function

```
    const path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;

    RNFS.readDir(path)
    .then((result) => {
        console.warn(result);
        const Files = [];

        if(result != undefined && result.length > 0){

            for(index in result) {
                const item = result[index];
                console.log(item);

                if(item.isFile()){

                    Files.push(item);
                }
            }

            if(Files.length > 0) {

                callback(Files);
            }
            else{

                callback(null);
            }
        }
        else{
            callback(null);
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {

        console.log('err in reading files');
        console.log(err);
        callback(null);
    })
```

But i want to read the directory and it's subdirectory and the files belongs to them, is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

I've achieved copying recursively from something in assets, to something in the document directory, like this:

```js
import FileSystem from "react-native-fs";

async copyRecursive(source, destination) {
    console.log(`${source} => ${destination}`);
    const items = await FileSystem.readDirAssets(source);

    console.log(`mkdir ${destination}/`);
    await FileSystem.mkdir(destination);

    await items.forEach(async item => {
      if (item.isFile()) {
        console.log(`f ${item.path}`);

        const destPath =
          FileSystem.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/" + source + "/" + item.name;

        console.log(`cp ${item.path} ${destPath}`);
        await FileSystem.copyFileAssets(item.path, destPath);
      } else {
        console.log(`d ${item.path}/`);

        // Restart with expanded path
        const subDirectory = source + "/" + item.name;
        const subDestination = destination + "/" + item.name;
        await this.copyRecursive(subDirectory, subDestination);
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      androidReady: true
    });
}
```